# When I am trying to read data from a CSV file using StreamReader(C#) with unity, I am facing Invalid Id 0x00000000. error

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to pick a CSV file from my mobile phone and read it using StreamReader.
I am using Unity 2020.3.2f1. I am using a paid unity asset "Native Android Goodies" to pick up a csv file from the users android phone using the following code as documented by the asset owner.

```
    const string mimeType = "application/CSV";

    AGFilePicker.PickFile(file =>
    {
        var msg = "Picked file: " + file;
        Debug.Log(msg);
        AGUIMisc.ShowToast(msg);

        Debug.Log(file.DisplayName);
        
        Debug.Log(file.OriginalPath);
        
        csvread.ReadCSV(file.OriginalPath);
        
    }, error => AGUIMisc.ShowToast("Picking File" + error),
    mimeType
    );
```

This code gives me the desired FilePickerResult and it calls the "ReadCSV" function created by me in another namespace which tries to read the CSV file as received from the picker using the path that the callback returns(file.OriginalPath). The code for the ReadCSV function is as follows:

```
if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
            {
                string s;
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Debug.Log(s);
                }
            }
        }
```

here the path is file.OriginalPath from the callback.
The issue I am facing is that this ReadCSV code gives me an error "Invalid Id 0x00000000." as shown by the android LogCat
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBJW0.png)

[image]

Can you help me resolve this issue?

Additional details -

- I have constructed a CSV file(which i cannot disclose).
- I downloaded the file on my mobile phone, then when I press a button in the scene, the PickFile function gets called(the first code mentioned).
- This function provides a callback in return which has the path, display name, and size and creation timestamp of the file picked.
- when the file picking is successful, I call the function "ReadCSV" as shown in the code and then the implementation of ReadCSV is also provided above(the second one).
- now, the file is getting picked from my device but the problem is when the function ReadCSV gets called. It seems that it states my file as invalid(hence the error) or maybe there is something wrong with my implementation of streamreader. I am not really sure why does it give me this error

Comment: There is insufficient info to recreate the problem. But it sounds like the csv file doesn’t contain what your code expects although there’s no mention of any form of id in the code

Comment: the code does work when i put the csv file in Resources folder in unity and use Resource.Load function

Comment: That doesn’t change the fact you haven’t provided us with any method to recreate the issue.

Comment: I have added additional details, i hope i was able to explain what is it that i am really facing issue with. I am sorry but I cannot share any screenshots for official purposes.

Comment: I have used the "Native Android Goodies" asset which is available in the asset store of unity